# Proving the convergence and finding the limit of a sequence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, arithmetic

I am having trouble proving the convergence and finding the limit of the sequence $\left(a_{n}\right)$ given by $a_{1}=\sqrt{3}$ and $a_{n}=\sqrt{3+2 a_{n-1}}$. I need to show that the sequence is convergent and determine its limit.

Here is my attempt at solving the problem:

Firstly, I noticed that the sequence is increasing because $a_{n}=\sqrt{3+2 a_{n-1}}>a_{n-1}$ for all $n>1$. To show that 3 is an upper bound, I started by assuming that $a_{n} \leq 3$ for all $n$. Then, I squared both sides of the recurrence relation and simplified to get:

$$a_{n}^{2}-2 a_{n-1}=3$$

Since $a_{n-1} \geq a_{1}=\sqrt{3}$, we have:

$$a_{n}^{2}-2 \sqrt{3} \leq 3$$

Solving for $a_{n}$, we get:

$$a_{n} \leq \sqrt{6}$$

Therefore, $3 \leq a_{n} \leq \sqrt{6}$ for all $n$, and since the sequence is increasing, it is bounded and therefore convergent.

However, I am stuck on how to determine the limit of the sequence. I would appreciate any help or hints on how to proceed with finding the limit.

Comment: The limit $a$ satsifies $a=\sqrt {3+2a}$.

Comment: Note:  $3\not\le\sqrt6$

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is incorrect. How do you know that $a_n$ increases? Why $\sqrt{3+2a_{n-1}}>a_n$? And, you already assumed that $a_n\le 3$ for any $n$, which is what you wanted to show. One may solve as follows.

(1) I claim that for any $n$, $1\le a_n\le 3$. This holds for $n = 1$, and if this holds for $n = k$, then $5\le 3+2a_n\le 9$, and $\sqrt{5}\le\sqrt{3+2a_n}\le 3$, so that $\sqrt{5}\le a_{n+1}\le 3$ and the same bound holds for $n = k+1$.

(2) $a_n$ is increasing. Solving $\sqrt{3+2a_n}\ge a_n$ gives $3+2a_n\ge a_n^2$, $(a_n-1)^2\le 4$, which is correct since $1\le a_n\le 3$.

Hence the sequence is bounded and monotone, so converges. Then the sequence $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3+2a_n}$ must converge to the same limit $a$, and by the limit laws we have $a = \sqrt{3+2a}$. Solving this gives $a = -1$ or $3$, and $a=-1$ is impossible since the sequence increases and $a_1 = \sqrt{3}$. Thus it must converge to $3$.

Comment: $a=1$ is not a solution to $a^2=3+2a$; $a=-1$ is

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks. Edited my answer.

Comment: Your approach of showing that $1\le a_n\le 3$ for all $n$ makes sense to me. It follows easily from the recurrence relation, and I see how you used it to show that the sequence is bounded. I also understand your proof of the fact that $a_n$ is increasing. I see that you used the inequality $\sqrt{3+2a_n}\ge a_n$ to show that $(a_n-1)^2\le 4$, which is true since $1\le a_n\le 3$.

Comment: I also see that you used the fact that the sequence is bounded and monotone to conclude that it converges to some limit $a$, and then used the recurrence relation to find that $a = \sqrt{3+2a}$, which has only one positive solution, $a=3$, since $a_1=\sqrt{3}$. Therefore, the limit of the sequence is 3. 

Thank you for your help and for providing a clear and correct solution to the problem. I appreciate it!

Comment: One last comment: I did not use the inequality $\sqrt{3+2a_n}\ge a_n$ to show $(a_n-1)^2\le 4$, but the opposite. I used $(a_n-1)^2\le 4$ to show $\sqrt{3+2a_n}\ge a_n$.